# How do I change the Yes/No options in a tkinter askquestion prompt?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I have a [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) dialog box which uses `messagebox.askquestion` to ask if a user wants to delete a file.

```
from tkinter import messagebox

choice = messagebox.askquestion("Delete file", "Are you sure you want to delete this file?")
if choice == 'yes':
    print("Delete file")
```

Instead of using Yes/No as my options, I want to change them to explicitly say Delete/Cancel.

**How can I modify the Yes/No options in a `tkinter` prompt?**

[image: "Are you sure you want to delete this file?"]

Comment: I'm pretty sure tkinter doesn't support this and you'll have to roll your own custom message dialog.

Comment: The whole point of using the messagebox standard types is that they have standard buttons, with names that get automatically translated in standard ways. If you don't want that, you _can_ dig into it and fiddle with the widgets during creation, but it's more work than just creating your own dialog box, so why?

Comment: Your best option is to use `Toplevel()` and create your own messagebox.